# Allow text overflow despite data in adjacent cells

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to have text populate in a cell and allow it to overflow into adjacent cells even though there is data in those cells? Here is my layout and situation:

I have a worksheet that acts as a "Report" sheet which populates data based on drop down selections at the top of the report sheet. The user can select any one of 8 countries to view that specific data, and the report sheet populates cells D16 through P25. The user can also select to view all 8 countries. In this instance, country data will populate in blocks of data (D16:P25, D27:P36, D38:P47, etc.) When looking at only one country, the other cells with data are blank (the formulas return "").

I need the text overflow now because I was asked to incorporate a summary of applicable limitations below the first data table when viewing only one country in the report. For example, if the report is selected to view Belgium, the data populates in cells D16:P26. Now, I need to show in cell D18:D22 a summary of the local laws. I can incorporate the necessary text using IF statements into column D, but it is cut off because there are formulas in columns E - P currently returning no values that need to return values for the "All Countries" view.

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: As you've described it, it is not possible. The only way I see this working would be to have the cells in E:P blank and populate with a formula using something like `Worksheet_Change` depending on some condition. Alternatively, switch to a three letter [ISO 3166-1 alpha-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) country code.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use VBA to fill in the data when the user selects an element in the dropdownbox. When handling this change, you should actually clear the cells that are giving empty results, instead of having formulas in there that don't do anything useful.

Comment: Just starting to learn VBA, so the sheet uses all formulas since I do not know how to write the macros.